# oracle update only first occurrence

Tags: database, oracle

I have table with two columns

```
rule_id , passenger_type
```

with

```
PRIMARY KEY (rule_id , passenger_type)
```

I'm trying to update passenger_type='CNN' where
passenger_type in ('C02','C03','C04')

but only the first occurrence for each rule_id

I'm using oracle db

for example:

```
+--------------------------+
| rule_id   passenger_type |
+--------------------------+
| 1         ADT            |
| 1         CH2            |
| 2         SWR            |
| 3         INF            |
| 1         CH3            |
| 2         CH4            |
| 2         CH3            |
| 3         ADT            |
+--------------------------+
```

result expected:

```
+--------------------------+
| rule_id   passenger_type |
+--------------------------+
| 1         ADT            |
| 1         CNN            |
| 2         SWR            |
| 3         INF            |
| 1         CH3            |
| 2         CNN            |
| 2         CH3            |
| 3         ADT            |
+--------------------------+
```

Answer (score 2):

without a proper sequence to the table the idea of "first occurrence" is a bit woolly, but this would update one row for each rule_id

```
update dg_test d
set passenger_type  = 'CNN'
where (d.rule_id, d.passenger_type) in (select x.rule_id, min(x.passenger_type )
                                        from dg_test x
                                        where x.rule_id = d.rule_id
                                        group by x.rule_id)
```

Comment: i need to update the first occurrence only where passenger_type in ('C02','C03','C04'). I updated my question and add exmaple